# OpenVPN Authentication/Decrypt packet error

Tags: ssl, openvpn, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to connect a laptop running Windos 10 to an Ubuntu 16.04 server running OpenVPN.

The Client keeps getting this error:

```
 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491498025,WAIT,,,,,,
 Connection reset, restarting [0]
 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491498025,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,
```

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) to setup OpenVPN. Everything is default except I changed to port 443 and tcp.

On the server I am seeing this error from "Systemctl status openvpn@server":

```
 ovpn-server[4627]: [IP ADDR] Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
 ovpn-server[4627]: [IP ADDR] SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
 ovpn-server[4627]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET][IP ADDR]
 ovpn-server[4627]: [IP ADDR] TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET][IP ADDR], sid=5bf6806d 9c9b6639
 ovpn-server[4627]:[IP ADDR] Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed
 ovpn-server[4627]: [IP ADDR] TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET][IP ADDR]
 ovpn-server[4627]: [IP ADDR] Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
 ovpn-server[4627]: [IP ADDR] SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

**server.conf**:

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert KICLAB-HV-01.crt
key KICLAB-HV-01.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0 
mode server
tls-server
cipher AES-128-CBC    # AES
auth SHA256           # SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

**base.conf:**

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote [Internal LAN IP for testing] 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256 
key-direction 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

**Client Log**

```
Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET][IP:443} [nonblock]
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491826387,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
TCP connection established with [AF_INET][IP:443}
TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET][IP:443}
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491826388,WAIT,,,,,,
Connection reset, restarting [0]
SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491826388,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,,,,
Restart pause, 5 second(s)
TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET][IP:443}
Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET][IP:443} [nonblock]
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491826393,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
TCP connection established with [AF_INET][IP:443}
TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET][IP:443}
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491826394,WAIT,,,,,,
Connection reset, restarting [0]
SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491826394,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,,,,
Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Current output of "Systemctl Status openvpn@server" (Note, [IP] is actually not the correct IP for the client.  Is that a problem?):

```
MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
IFCONFIG POOL LIST
MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=1024 maxevents=1028
Initialization Sequence Completed
TCP connection established with [AF_INET][IP]:48758
[IP]:48758 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET][IP]:48758, sid=9ab50ac0 a37efe04
[IP]:48758 TLS Error: reading acknowledgement record from packet
[IP]:48758 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Apr 10 08:36:24 [host] ovpn-server[2191]: [IP]:48758 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ensure that `key-direction` is not the same in the client and server config?  One should be `0` and the other a `1`.

Comment: I did, server is set to `1` and client is set to `0`. :(

Comment: Why don't you edit your post and add both client and server configs.  Remove hostnames and unneeded comments etc first.

Comment: Added config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got no certificate for client in your configs. You should [generate one signed by the same CA, which you use on your server](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/EasyRSA3-OpenVPN-Howto) and add it to the client.conf like this:

```
ca "ca.crt"
cert "client.crt"
key "client.key"
```

Comment: Well there we go.  The guide had a script to create certs.  Somehow I skipped that part, I thought it was done.  Anyway, it works now! Thank!

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenVPN website:

> The --tls-auth option uses a static pre-shared key (PSK) that must be
>   generated in advance and shared among all peers.

You have it on your server as:

```
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
```

But on the client, you have it commented out:

```
;tls-auth ta.key 1
...
key-direction 1
```

The second argument to `tls-auth` is the key-direction, therefore you do not need to repeat it using the `key-direction` stanza.

On your server, simply remove the `key-direction 0` line, and on your client remove both the comment delimiter (`;`) and the `key-direction 1` line.

Of course, the `ta.key` needs to also be on your client machine first before the above will actually work - copy it there securely with `scp` or similar.

Comment: Ok, so optionally, if I were to just comment out all of those lines, should I be able to work without the key altogether?  I tried doing so, then restarting the service, but I am still getting an `TLS error: reading acknowledgement record from packet` `Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting` on the server; so it looks like it's still checking?

Comment: I have restarted both the client and server.  I am no longer getting the HMAC error, only the two TLS errors now.

Comment: I have just added the client log after trying a connection again.

Comment: Yes, I had the firewall shutdown on both client and server for testing.  Problem resolved - missing certs. Thanks again!

Comment: Doh!  Glad you got it fixed :-)